# Customize Python unittest report with HTML or Textile

Tags: python, html, customization, unit-testing, textile

I'm using unittest for testing my python code. I'm seeking a way that I can do the following:

1. Customize the report of test run.
2. Export it as HTML or Textile document.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [HTMLTestRunner](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html), such a great and simple tool.

Answer (score 3):

[testoob](https://launchpad.net/testoob) should support your reporting requirements (not sure whether it supports `textile` reporting, but it definitely does support HTML reporting).